# Is it possible that multiple apps having same name in springboard?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

As I researched that you can not use same app name in iTune whenever you are submitting app is App Store.
but I want to know that is possible multiple apps having same name in springboard?

Comment: It might be possible to have multiple app with the same name but the bundle identifier has to differ.

Comment: yes in my case I have different bundle identifier for each targets

Comment: Yes, its possible, however apple might reject the app if they knew the app has same name.

Comment: name in appstore will be different, but in springboard i want same name of all apps

Comment: [This quora link](http://qr.ae/EiTz2) says you can have same name on springboard.

Comment: yes I saw that link but that link is too old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official rule against it. For example, both Shazam and Shazam Encore appear on the home screen as "Shazam". But if Apple thinks you're doing something weird, or shady, or not in the user's best interest, they might reject your app anyway.

Obviously your bundle identifiers must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but the bundle identifiers must be unique.